# Two threads reading same list but from different ends

Tags: java, multithreading, listiterator

i have a list , i need to traverse the list by two threads. One reading from top to bottom and other one from bottom to top. And when they intersect reading should stop.

For iterating over the list i can use ListIterator, but i am not able to think how these threads going to read from same list?

Comment: what do u mean `how to read from same list` ? pass a reference of the list to both threads ?!

Comment: do the threads edit the list? how precise must the stopping be? For example, if the threads read a couple more items after intersecting, would it be bad?

Comment: @ThijsSteel, No threads are only reading from the list. Yes, its bad to read to items after intersect. So aim is to read all the list but from different ends without interscting.

Answer (score 1):

Since the threads are only reading, there is no need to use a thread safe version of the list.

To make sure the threads stop reading when they intersect you will need to synchronize them, so before reading another item, they should check whether that item is available. A naive way to implement this is to store the current index in each thread and let the other thread have access to that index (make sure to synchronize that index). This would lead to a lot of overhead though.

A better idea is to work in batches. Divide the list in sections of for example 16 items. Then the threads can read the entire batch before needing to check for intersection.

Comment: +1 for "batching"  @Rogger296, Assuming that your reason for using two threads is to speed up a computation, the more work that the threads can do between synchronization points, the more benefit you will get from using multiple threads.  Beginners often are dismayed to learn that poorly designed multi-threaded computations---too much coupling between threads---can be _slower_ than the single-threaded version.

Comment: The list i am using here is having File size as one of attribute. And on the basis of which List is sorted descending order. So the Thread T1 reading from the top is moving slowly because it has to cater heavy files where as thread T2 is moving rapidly because it is reading from bottom of list where file size is very low. I can not use batch because it will load the Thread T1 with heavy set of files. So requirement is every time Threads get single element from List.

Comment: @Rogger296 You could have thread one working in batch size 1 or 2 and have thread one working in a larger batch size. You could possibly even adapt batch size on the fly

Answer (score 0):

you can partition the list that is one thread will read from 0 to half and second will read half+1 to last.

```
class PrintList implements Runnable{

    private List list = new ArrayList();
    public PrintList(List list){
        this.list = list;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
     if(Thread.currentThread().getName() != null && Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("thread1")){
         int mid =list.size()/2;
         for(int i = 0; i< mid;i++){
            // System.out.println("Thread 1 "+list.get(i));
         }
     }else if(Thread.currentThread().getName() != null && Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("thread2")){

         for(int i = mid; i<list.size(); i++){
             //System.out.println("Thread 2 "+list.get(i));
         }
     }  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Requirement is not to partition the list but read it by using two threads at the same time. T1 from top & T2  from bottom. List is sorted in descending order so T1 is reading heavy files and T2 is reading smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve this issue if you take into consideration that the total items processed by Thread A and the total items processed by Thread B will in the end be equal to the amount of items in the list.

So if you have a counter that decrements each time a thread wants to process the next element, you know you are done once the counter reaches zero.

```
public class MyThreadSyncer {
  protected final AtomicInteger elementCount;

  public MyThreadSyncer(final Collection c) {
    elementCount = new AtomicInteger(c.size());
  }

  public boolean canProcessNext() {
    return (this.elementCount.decrementAndGet() >= 0);
  }
}
```

Using this class each thread sets its own private counter (Thread A at 0, Thread B at size-1) and then checks like this:

```
if (this.threadSyncer.canProcessNext()) {
  this.theTasks[this.myPosition].process();

  this.myPosition += 1;  // this line in thread A
  this.myPosition -= 1;  // this line in thread B
}
```